# XQuery cardinality error on outputting results to text file

Tags: xquery, exist-db

Using XQuery 3.1 (under eXistDB 4.4), I have a function which returns a  serialized output of 710 delimited rows like these:

```
MS609-0001~ok~0001~1r~Deposition~De_Manso_Sanctarum_Puellarum_1~self~1245-05-27~Arnald_Garnier_MSP-AU~self
MS609-0002~ok~0002~1r~Deposition~De_Manso_Sanctarum_Puellarum_1~MS609-0001~1245-05-27~Guilhem_de_Rosengue_MSP-AU~MS609-0001
MS609-0003~ok~0003~1r~Deposition~De_Manso_Sanctarum_Puellarum_1~MS609-0001~1245-05-27~Hugo_de_Mamiros_MSP-AU~MS609-0001
```

I get the above serialized results in another function that should store it in the directory `/db/apps/deheresi/documents` as a flatfile `depositions.txt`

```
let $x := schedule:deposition-textfile()

return xmldb:store(concat($globalvar:URIdb,"documents"), "deposition.txt", $x)
```

But when I execute the `xmldb:store` action, it returns an error:

```
Description: err:XPTY0004 checking function parameter 3 
in call xmldb:store(untyped-value-check[xs:string, 
concat("/db/apps/deheresi/", "documents")], "depositions.txt", $x): 

XPTY0004: The actual cardinality for parameter 3 does not 
match the cardinality declared in the function's signature: 
xmldb:store($collection-uri as xs:string, 
$resource-name as xs:string?, 
$contents as item()) xs:string?. 

Expected cardinality: exactly one, got 710.
```

How do I get these serialized results into the text file?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I tried wrapping the serialized output in `<result>` and that fixes the problem of cardinality, BUT it writes the `<result>` element to the file as plain text:

```
<result>MS609-0001~ok~0001~1r~Deposition~De_Manso_Sanctarum_Puellarum_1~self~1245-05-27~Arnald_Garnier_MSP-AU~self
MS609-0002~ok~0002~1r~Deposition~De_Manso_Sanctarum_Puellarum_1~MS609-0001~1245-05-27~Guilhem_de_Rosengue_MSP-AU~MS609-0001
MS609-0003~ok~0003~1r~Deposition~De_Manso_Sanctarum_Puellarum_1~MS609-0001~1245-05-27~Hugo_de_Mamiros_MSP-AU~MS609-0001</result>
```

Even if I add:

```
declare option exist:serialize "method=text";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems quite clear. The return type of `schedule:deposition-textfile()` is not acceptable to `xmldb:store()`. You want a single string,  not 710.

Either change the return type of your function,  or search the [xQuery function documentation](http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/index.htmlv) for `xmldb:store` to find a suitable alternative for your returntype.

Comment: That fixed it: I had forgotten to put `as xs:string` as return type on the original function. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the function you are calling, but perhaps you should use string-join() to combine the 710 strings into one, with a newline separator.